# JSONAPI - Difference between self and related in a links resource

Tags: json-api

Why is the [`self` and `related`](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-relationships) references different in the below JSONAPI resource?  Aren't they pointing to the same resource?  What is the difference between going to `/articles/1/relationships/tags` and `/articles/1/tags`?

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "/articles/1/relationships/tags",
    "related": "/articles/1/tags"
  },
  "data": [
    { "type": "tags", "id": "2" },
    { "type": "tags", "id": "3" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can read about that here: https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/508.

Basically, with `/articles/1/relationships/tags` response will be object which represents relationship between `articles` and `tags`. The response could be something like this (what you put in your question):

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "/articles/1/relationships/tags",
    "related": "/articles/1/tags"
  },
  "data": [
    { "type": "tags", "id": "2" },
    { "type": "tags", "id": "3" }
  ]
}
```

This response gives only the necessary data (in primary data attribute - *data*) to manipulate the relationship and not resources connected with relationship. That being said, you'll call `/articles/1/relationships/tags` if you want to **create** new relationship, **add** a new tag (basically updating relationship) to article, **read** which tags belong to article (you only need identity to search them on server) or **delete** article tags.

On the other hand, calling `/articles/1/tags` will respond with tags as **primary data** with all the other properties that they have (*articles*, *relationships*, *links*, and other top-level attributes such *include*, *emphasized text*, *links* and/or *jsonapi*).

Comment: Do you need to send a payload to the self link if you're trying to create or delete a relationship? Also what does this mean: "read which tags belong to article (you only need identity to search them on server)" What would the link be to read the tags which belong to the article? Isn't that the same as visiting root/articles/1/tags?

Answer (score 4):

They are different. Here is an example from my project.

Try `Get http://localhost:3000/phone-numbers/1/relationships/contact` you will get response like this:

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://localhost:3000/phone-numbers/1/relationships/contact",
    "related": "http://localhost:3000/phone-numbers/1/contact"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "contacts",
    "id": "1"
  }
}
```

You **didn't** get the `attributes` and `relationships` which is probably you want to retrieve.

Then
Try `Get http://localhost:3000/phone-numbers/1/contact` you will get response like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "contacts",
    "links": {
      "self": "http://localhost:3000/contacts/1"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "name-first": "John",
      "name-last": "Doe",
      "email": "john.doe@boring.test",
      "twitter": null
    },
    "relationships": {
      "phone-numbers": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://localhost:3000/contacts/1/relationships/phone-numbers",
          "related": "http://localhost:3000/contacts/1/phone-numbers"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see you retrieved all the information you want, including the `attributes` and `relationships`.

But you should know that `relationships` can be used for some purpose. Please read http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-to-one-relationships as a sample.